# Customize review page totals text (shipping & handling (flat rate - fixed))

Tags: magento, checkout, summary

On the review order page in onepage checkout in magento I want to shorten the "Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed)" text (see http://d.pr/AAlb).
I want it to just read "Shipping & Handling" and remove the carrier/delivery type written in brackets

How can I do that? It's rendered with `$this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan);`, which gives me shipping cost+sub total. I don't know where to start from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation that I have done. This is a standard override (http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/). I did it this way so as to not get too deep into the overriding system.

```
class Your_Company_Model_Address_Total_Shipping extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping
{

    /**
     * Collect totals information about shipping
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping
     */
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);

        $method = $address->getShippingMethod();

        if ($method) {
            foreach ($address->getAllShippingRates() as $rate) {
                if ($rate->getCode()==$method) {
                    $shippingDescription = $rate->getMethodTitle();
                    if (stripos($shippingDescription, ",") > -1)
                        $shippingDescription = substr($shippingDescription, 0, stripos($shippingDescription, ","));
                    $address->setShippingDescription(trim($shippingDescription, ' -'));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to make a module for this purpose, but I'm trying to overwrite the _fetch_ function and get rid of the part where it adds $address->getShippingDescription() to the $title.

I've never done this before, so it was trial&error, but I think I almost got it working. The module is called (as I can see in system.log), but checkout gets stuck before getting to the review-page. Maybe you could take a look at it and see what I did wrong: http://d.pr/LnR6 Thanks!

Comment: To me your code looked good, although I didn't try it out. Do you have NetBeans or something similar to step through the code? What happens when the cursor leaves your code? Your code is almost identical to what was there, just without a couple of lines (and those won't cause a problem). Considering your log is called, you probably have an error somewhere else.

Comment: For the outdated Inchoo link: http://web.archive.org/web/20140908084939/http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/